# How to authenticate user using Ueberauth and Guardian in Phoenix framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ueberauth

Is there any tutorial or help available which i can follow to authenticae users using Ueberauth and Guardian in Phoenix framework.

I have seen following post but it mostly talk about addict and passport libraries

[How to implement user authentication in phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805275/how-to-implement-user-authentication-in-phoenix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow following youtube video. It will guide you step by step regarding authentication in Phoenix/Elixir app with [Ueberauth](https://github.com/ueberauth/ueberauth) and [Guardian](https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6Z-sDSJ3sE

You can also download or see complete source code of an example project here

https://github.com/ylankgz/shlack

Comment: While there is good information in the 3.5 hours of video, it would be nice to see a written guide.

Comment: Anyone looking for a written tutorial, I recommend this blog post from thoughtbot: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/authentication-in-elixir-web-applications-with-guardian-part-1